# h:outputText line break for long words within strings

Tags: string, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to tell `h:outputText` of JSF (2.0) to insert a line break (or even better: A custom string like "-") into very long words within strings?
My problem is that my data-table (PrimeFaces) gets too wide when I have a very long word within a string with no spaces. It works when I have a long text "normal" words, then the next word is printed in the next line.

While I could use a converter, this would still mean that I have to look for long words within a string and then cut them every time I display the text. This would work somehow for a small amount of data, but needs a lot of processing power when the database is getting bigger (and it will).

I also could scan the string for long words before inserting into the database, which would mean that I only have to process the string once, but also that i'm not able to fully reconstruct the original string if I'd ever need it.

Does anyone have any input on this?

Thank you in advance and best regards,
Robert

Comment: @ Robert M. Hi i have the same problem. Balus C answer not working for me but i am using jsf1.2 if u show ur code then it will be useful for me.

Comment: BalusC's solution does not depend on the JSF version in use. It is a plain CSS solution. The styleClass attribute exists in JSF 1.2 and renders a "class" attribute to the resulting HTML output. If it doesn't work this is a problem in your HTML/CSS. You could try to set a fixed width for the parent HTML element.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set CSS [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap) property of the element in question to `break-word`.

```
<h:outputText styleClass="someClass" />
```

with

```
.someClass {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me. The css class is showing in matched css rules in firebug, but I dnt know why long words are not breaking.

Comment: @djaqeel: A prerequirement is that the element has a fixed width.

Comment: Oh thanks. You are right. When I give fixed width, it works fine, but I want to give % widht. In %age width, word-wrapping is fine but the span itself takes the whole width(as if it calculates the span's width before applying word-wrap).

Answer (score 11):

```
 <h:outputText value="Very Wordy&lt;br /&gt;Table Column&lt;br /&gt;Heading" escape="false" />
```

**Output**

```
Very Wordy
Table Column
Heading
```

Comment: Source: [blog.michaelscepaniak.com](http://blog.michaelscepaniak.com/jsf-render-line-breaks-in-the-outputtext-tag)

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished by two steps

1)Apply style as table-layout:fixed to the panelGrid

**E.g:** `<h:panelGrid style="table-layout:fixed;">`

2) Then apply style of word-wrap break-word to the `<h:outputText />` as below.

**E.g:** `<h:outputText  style="word-wrap:break-word;">`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

if you have very long word in String you can use `word-break: break-all;` like this:

```
<h:outputText value="111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" style="word-break: break-all;"/>
```

but it required CSS3. 
link: [word-break](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use h:inputTextarea rather than h:outputText , don't remember set readonly attribute true and remove border like this:

```
<h:inputTextarea  rows="10" cols="50" readonly="true" value="multiline String"  style="border-color: white"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me. Using "white-space: normal" fixed it.

```
<h:outputText value="long text" style="white-space: normal"/>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes