# Need Help Figuring Out Why Text Is Overflowing my h:outputText Within A p:panelGrid with Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

Like the title says, I am using PrimeFaces, and I have an h:outputText within a p:PanelGrid. Whenever there is a very long, unbroken string put into the "value" field of the h:outputText, it overflows the span created by the h:outputText and the td created by the p:panelGrid, and runs off the right side of the page. It has to be a single, long, unbroken string of text, but it will always overflow its boundaries. I have tried adding style="overflow: scroll;" and style="width: 100px;", and other possible fixes, but nothing reigns in the text. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks for taking the time to read, and have a great day.

:-)

Comment: Would it be possible to add some small code example where this is still happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556980/jsf-houtputtext-line-break-for-long-words-within-strings see if that applies

Comment: Aksel Willgert - No, cannot provide any code. Sorry. I'll try your link when I get to work on Monday. Thanks for taking a look at this for me.

Comment: Provided an answer; just as a helpful suggestion, although you're using PrimeFaces this is really a CSS question. Tagging it with CSS might get a larger set of eyes on it.

Comment: Greg, I wasn't sure if it was CSS or Primefaces, because [using Firebug] I couldn't find any CSS that may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a static width won't help in and of itself. However, when width of the element is known (not set to "auto"), `overflow: scroll` should work fine as should `overflow:hidden`. Is it possible that the `overflow` rule is being overridden by a more specific rule elsewhere in one of your style sheets? That strikes me as the most likely culprit.

If it's OK to lose some of that information (accessing the full string on hover or clicking an icon, for example), you could combine the following:

```
.someElement {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

In browsers that support `text-overflow: ellipsis` (which isn't all browsers) you would see a neat ellipsis character at the truncation point. Otherwise it'll just kinda get cut off at the edge of your container.

To sum it up:

- overflow:scroll should already work. If it's not, there's another rule superseding it.
- you might want to consider the ellipsis solution instead of the scrollbar, if doing so doesn't break your project requirements

Comment: Greg ... thank you, but this didn't work either. As suggested by you, I'm going to repost this as a CSS and/or HTML issue. I can create a very simple HTML page and reproduce this error - I'll post it as an "Answer Your Question". Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, Brian. I tested with a fiddle just to make sure I was right (and I was)... what else could it be? Last thing I can think of is that your element has display:inline rather than display:block or display:inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

To all who have read and replied. This, as it turns out, is not a Primefaces issue, but an HTML/CSS issue. I will be reposting this question thusly. Thank you for taking the time to read and reply. Below is a simple HTML reproduction of my issue, along with some of the suggestions mentioned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> problem </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            span.troubleSpan {
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4> problem </h4>
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="troubleSpan">asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```